# How to look up zsh completion definitions

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, function

Is there a way to lookup (just print the completion definition to stdout) currently loaded zsh completion functions.

I understand that they are stored somewhere on my fpath and I could do something like `ag $fpath completionname` to find the definition in the files. 
Is there a cleaner way, a zsh function or something to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name of the completion function for the command `foo` is `$_comps[foo]`.

To see the code of a function `myfunc`, run `echo -E $functions[myfunc]`, or just `echo $functions[myfunc]` if you have the [`bsd_echo`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-BSD_005fECHO) option on, or `print -rl $functions[myfunc]`. So to see the code of the completion function for the command `foo`, run `echo -E $functions[$_comps[foo]]`. Alternatively, run **[`which $_comps[foo]`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-which)** if the function name has no alias.

This shows the code without comments (and with normalized whitespace: it's a human-readable dump of the bytecode that zsh stores internally). If you want to see the original file defined in the code, run **[`whence -v $_comps[foo]`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-whence)** or `echo $functions_source[$_comps[foo]]`. The [`functions_source`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-functions_005fsource) array is only available if the [module `zsh/parameter`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module) is loaded (you can do this with `zmodload zsh/parameter`) and only since zsh 5.4.

If you haven't used the function yet, you'll see something like `builtin autoload -XU` instead of the code, and no path to the source. To see the path to the source, run **[`autoload -r $_comps[foo]`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-autoload)** first to make zsh resolve the path to the source, then you can display it with `which` or `whence` or `$functions_source`.

```
zmodload zsh/parameter
(($+_comps[foo])) &&
autoload -r $_comps[foo] &&
((+$functions_source[$_comps[foo]])) &&
cat $functions_source[$_comps[foo]]
```