# Auto-completion with shell function

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, function

The `zsh` function `cn`

```
function cn() {
    nmcli device wifi connect "$1" --ask
}
```

will prompt for a password and connect to the network `foo`, if
you type

```
cn foo
```

But it will not auto-complete `foo`, as when you write the nmcli
command in full.  How do I get auto-completion of the network
name?

I'm using zsh 5.7.1.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way in this specific case: make it an alias instead. This is possible because you can put `--ask` before the network name. Zsh expands aliases before doing completion by default.

```
alias cn='nmcli device wifi connect --ask'
```

---

If you use a function, you need to teach zsh about the arguments of the function: specify a completion function for `cn`, which may or may not be a custom function depending on what it has to do. (I assume that you're using the “new completion system”, i.e. you have `compinit` in your `.zshrc`.)

Here the function is a simple wrapper around another command. So see how this command's arguments are completed.

```
% echo $_comps[nmcli]
_networkmanager
```

For most commands, the name of the completion function is the command name with an underscore before it, but for `nmcli`, in recent zsh versions, it's a different name. (It may be `_nmcli` on your system if you're running zsh &lt5.5.) Next, look at [the source code](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.6/Completion/Linux/Command/_networkmanager) to see how the function works. See [How to look up zsh completion definitions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509869/how-to-look-up-zsh-completion-definitions/509944#509944) for more information.

You don't need to understand everything (and good luck trying: the completion system is complex!) but for most commands it's reasonably easy to figure out how a specific subcommand or option is completed. In zsh ≥5.5 it's the function [`_nm_device_wifi_connect`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.6/Completion/Linux/Command/_networkmanager#L254) which in turn calls [`_nm_device_wifi_ssids`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.6/Completion/Linux/Command/_networkmanager#L357). In zsh ≤5.4 I think `_nmcli` doesn't support this particular command line syntax (the syntax of `nmcli` keeps changing, so by the time zsh releases a version, its `nmcli` completion code tends to be already out of date).

With zsh ≥5.5, you can associate `_nm_device_wifi_ssids` with `cn`. However, there's a twist: if you first complete `cn` without having ever completed `nmcli`, zsh won't know where to find `_nm_device_wifi_ssids`, because completion functions are loaded on demand and this mechanism only knows how to find the main function `_networkmanager`, not auxiliary functions like `_nm_XXX`. See [Can I use a helper function from a ZSH completion file in another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403820/can-i-use-a-helper-function-from-a-zsh-completion-file-in-another/403841#403841) and [overwrite and reuse existing function in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450043/overwrite-and-reuse-existing-function-in-zsh/450133#450133) for how to work around this.

Here the code of the zsh 5.5 function is simple, and zsh 5.4 doesn't have a corresponding function anyway. So the easiest solution is to copy the relevant part of the zsh 5.5 code into a new function.

```
function _cn {
    compadd -- ${(f)"$(_call_program nmcli nmcli -t -f ssid device wifi list)"}
}
compdef `_cn` cn
```

Comment: the first method doesn't work for me.  there are completions, but not of network names.

Comment: in 5.7.1, i have a function called `_nm`, but no other function beginning with `_nm_`

Comment: @Toothrot As I mention in my answer, the `_nm_XXX` functions will appear once you've completed `nmcli` at least once.

Comment: would it perhaps also be possible to have something like an 
expandable alias (there would be a more correct term), such that
typing `nc<tab>` would put `nmcli device wifi connect | --ask`
on the readline, with the cursor at the tab?